# invariance of angles under lattice automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-lattices

Let $L$ be a lattice, $x,y\in L$ and $g\in Aut(L)$.
Does this imply
$$<x,y>=<g(x),g(y)>,$$
in other words, are angles or inner products between any two lattice vectors invariant under lattice automorphisms?

Comment: Consider that every element of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Indeed, this would yield automorphisms that change inner products.
However, I have checked the definition of lattice automorphisms as in Conway ("Sphere packings, lattices and groups"):

"The automorphism group [...] is the set of distance-preserving transformations (or isometries) of the space that fix the origin and take the lattice to itself."

Thus, by definition, lattice automorphisms are distance-preserving and if I understand this correctly (could someone confirm this?), this means preserving inner products.
It should also be like this, otherwise many things I have read make no sense.